# C# generics method selection

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to write generic algorithms in C# that can work with geometric entities of different dimension.

In the following contrived example I have `Point2` and `Point3`, both implementing a simple `IPoint` interface.

Now I have a function `GenericAlgorithm` that calls a function `GetDim`.  There are multiple definitions of this function based on the type.  There is also a fall-back function that is defined for anything that implements `IPoint`.

I initially expected the output of the following program to be 2, 3.  However, it is 0, 0.

```cs
interface IPoint {
    public int NumDims { get; } 
}

public struct Point2 : IPoint {
    public int NumDims => 2;
}

public struct Point3 : IPoint {
    public int NumDims => 3;
}

class Program
{
    static int GetDim<T>(T point) where T: IPoint => 0;
    static int GetDim(Point2 point) => point.NumDims;
    static int GetDim(Point3 point) => point.NumDims;

    static int GenericAlgorithm<T>(T point) where T : IPoint => GetDim(point);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point2 p2;
        Point3 p3;
        int d1 = GenericAlgorithm(p2);
        int d2 = GenericAlgorithm(p3);
        Console.WriteLine("{0:d}", d1);        // returns 0 !!
        Console.WriteLine("{0:d}", d2);        // returns 0 !!
    }
}
```

OK, so for some reason the concrete type information is lost in `GenericAlgorithm`. I don't fully understand why this happens, but fine.  If I can't do it this way, what other alternatives do I have?

Comment: "There is also a fall-back function " What is the purpose of this, exactly? The whole point of implementing an interface is to guarantee that the `NumDims` property is available. Why are you ignoring it in some cases?

Comment: So it compiles, basically.  Initially, I thought the fall back function is required if at run-time the JIT compiler can't find a specialized implementation for `GetDim` (i.e. I pass a `Point4` but `GetDim<Point4>` doesn't exist).  However, it doesn't seem the compiler bothers to look for a specialized implementation.

Comment: @woggy: You say "it doesn't seem the compiler bothers to look for a specialized implementation" as if this were a matter of laziness on the part of designers and implementers. It's not. It's a matter of how generics are represented in .NET. It's just not the same kind of specialization as templating in C++. A generic method isn't compiled separately for each type argument - it's compiled once. There are pros and cons of this, certainly, but it's not a matter of "bothering".

Comment: @jonskeet Apologies if my language choice was poor, I'm sure there are complexities here that I have not considered.  My understanding was the compiler does not compile separate functions for reference types, but it does for value types/structs, is that correct?

Comment: @woggy: That's the *JIT*-compiler, which is an entirely separate matter from the C# compiler - and it's the C# compiler that performs overload resolution. The IL for the generic method is only generated once - not once per specialization.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This method:

```cs
static int GenericAlgorithm<T>(T point) where T : IPoint => GetDim(point);
```

... will *always* call `GetDim<T>(T point)`. The overload resolution is performed at *compile-time*, and at that stage there's no other applicable method.

If you want overload resolution to be called at *execution time*, you'd need to use dynamic typing, e.g.

```cs
static int GenericAlgorithm<T>(T point) where T : IPoint => GetDim((dynamic) point);
```

But it's generally a better idea to use inheritance for this - in your example, obviously you could just have the single method and return `point.NumDims`. I assume in your real code there's some reason the equivalent is trickier to do, but without more context we can't advise on how to use inheritance to perform the specialization. Those are your options though:

- Inheritance (preferred) for specialization based on the execution-time type of the target
- Dynamic typing for execution-time overload resolution

Comment: The real situation is I have an `AxisAlignedBoundingBox2` and `AxisAlignedBoundingBox3`.  I have a `Contains`static method that is used to determine if a *collection* of boxes contains a `Line2` or `Line3` (which one depends on the type of the boxes).  The algorithm logic between the two types is exactly the same, except the number of dimensions is different.  There are also calls to `Intersect` internally that need to be specialized to the correct type. I want to avoid virtual function calls/dynamic, which is why I am using generics ...of course, I can just copy/paste the code and move on.

Comment: @woggy: It's quite hard to visualize that from just a description. If you want help trying to do this using inheritance, I suggest you create a new question with a minimal but complete example.

Comment: OK, will do, I'll accept this answer for now as it seems I haven't provided a good example.

Answer (score 6):

As of C# 8.0 you should be able to provide a default implementation for your interface, rather than requiring the generic method.

```
interface IPoint {
    int NumDims { get => 0; }
}
```

Implementing a generic method and overloads per `IPoint` implementation also violates the Liskov Substitution Principle (the L in SOLID). You would be better to push the *algorithm* into each `IPoint` implementation, which means you should only need a single method call:

```
static int GetDim(IPoint point) => point.NumDims;
```

Answer (score 3):

## Visitor Pattern

as an alternative to `dynamic` usage, you may want to use a ***Visitor pattern*** as below:

```
interface IPoint
{
    public int NumDims { get; }
    public int Accept(IVisitor visitor);
}

public struct Point2 : IPoint
{
    public int NumDims => 2;

    public int Accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        return visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

public struct Point3 : IPoint
{
    public int NumDims => 3;

    public int Accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        return visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

public class Visitor : IVisitor
{
    public int Visit(Point2 toVisit)
    {
        return toVisit.NumDims;
    }

    public int Visit(Point3 toVisit)
    {
        return toVisit.NumDims;
    }
}

public interface IVisitor<T>
{
    int Visit(T toVisit);
}

public interface IVisitor : IVisitor<Point2>, IVisitor<Point3> { }

class Program
{
    static int GetDim<T>(T point) where T : IPoint => 0;
    static int GetDim(Point2 point) => point.NumDims;
    static int GetDim(Point3 point) => point.NumDims;

    static int GenericAlgorithm<T>(T point) where T : IPoint => point.Accept(new Visitor());

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point2 p2;
        Point3 p3;
        int d1 = GenericAlgorithm(p2);
        int d2 = GenericAlgorithm(p3);
        Console.WriteLine("{0:d}", d1);        // returns 2
        Console.WriteLine("{0:d}", d2);        // returns 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you define GetDim function in class and interface？
Actually, you do not need to define GetDim function, just use the property NumDims.